# Strange OutOfMemoryError on Stream

Tags: scala

Why do I get OutOfMemoryError for the following code?

Stream.from(1).filter(n => (1 to 20).forall(x => n % x == 0)).head

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Streams have some limitations on the JVM. The problem you are seeing here is that the Stream you are creating with `Stream.from(1)` is put on the stack and thus the JVM refuses to garbage collect it. The predicate you are passing to the `filter` call lets the Stream grow to `232792560` elements.

If you use an `Iterator` you can work around this limitation:

```
Iterator.from(1).filter(n => (1 to 20).forall(x => n % x == 0)).next
```

Comment: Shame on you for giving away the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Streams are lazily evaluated, but they *store the results of their evaluations*.  Thus, unless you want to traverse through them multiple times, you should use `Iterator` instead.